# Pre-Commit Windows Hook to Require Issue Number in Comment

Tags: powershell, batch-file, svn, visualsvn-server, pre-commit-hook

I am looking for a way to reject commits that lack a bug issue number in their comments. The system I am setting up uses VisualSVN Server on Windows Server 2012 and MantisBT on a LAMP server for bug tracking. This question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499098/restricting-subversion-commits-if-the-jira-issue-key-is-not-in-the-commit-messag), but the repository in that case was on a LAMP server. I am looking for a batch or PowerShell script which does not depend on PHP or compiling code. Ideally, the hook would require "issue #1234" or "issues #12 and #34" to be present somewhere in the commit message.

Comment: Try adapting [this batch file](https://gist.github.com/utopius/5950220) and post back in case of problems.

Comment: I already have a batch script to check message length. The key to what I am asking, of course, is how to perform a regular expression search on the commit text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this batch file](https://gist.github.com/utopius/5950220):

After this block:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set REPOS=%1
set TXN=%2

set SVNLOOK="%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\svnlook.exe"

REM Concatenate all the lines in the commit message
FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %%g IN (`%SVNLOOK% log -t %TXN% %REPOS%`) DO SET M=!M!%%g
```

add the check:

```
echo !M! | findstr /i /r /c:"issues* *#[0-9][0-9]*" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo "Sorry, commit message should reference an issue" >&2
    exit /b 1
)
```

Comment: It looks like this will require a little adjustment. Your regex searches for "issues" but not "issue", and rejects my commit with a single issue reference.

Comment: No, it *does* search for `issue` too because an asterisk in regular expressions means 0 or more occurrences of the previous symbol.

Comment: You're right. The problem seems to be that in my comment I used a single digit issue number: "This refers to issue #1." while your regex requires two digits.

Comment: It would be nice to add /I to the findstr command to make the search case-insensitive. Otherwise "Issue #1" fails.

Comment: Thanks again. It looks from all my reading like /i and /I (capital i) do the same thing.